# Is the usage of "in addition" correct in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar

Is the following usage of "in addition" correct?

> Michael Jordan is the best player among the "4 NBA Pillars", which **in addition** includes Lebron James, Kobe Bryant and Magic Johnson.

The original sentence was phrased as follows:

> Michael Jordan is the best player among the "4 NBA Giants", the others being Lebron James, Kobe Bryant and Magic Johnson.

Comment: @andrew - (a) is the original version better? (b) can you elaborate on the redundancy? (c) why isn't "in addition to" proper?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with "in addition", but _also_ is less prolix and more idiomatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, my comments are incorrect.  If you use commas, there's really nothing wrong with your sentence:

> Michael Jordan is the best player of the "Four Pillars of the NBA", which, in addition, includes Lebron James. etc.

As P.E. Dant mentions in his comment, it's a little  *wordy*, meaning that you could write a shorter sentence.  But many native speakers love to write 100 words when 10 will do.

In this context, I would not use "in addition" because it implies that there is something *extra* beyond the defined group.  For example:

> Many airlines allow you to check two bags, but, in addition, you can bring a third bag as a "carry-on".
>
> In addition to native deer, you can often see elk and moose wandering through the streets of some small towns in Canada.

Here you've already defined a group of four people, so the others in the group are not "extra".  But you can use it if you want to mention someone else who should be in the group:

> The four pillars of the NBA includes Jordan, Bryant, James, and Johnson, who are all outstanding players.  Still, many think that, in addition to these, it should also include Kareem Abdul-Jabbar and Wilt Chamberlain.